# Padrino: determining route name in controller

Tags: routes, padrino

Is there a way to determine within the padrino controller what the route name is? For example, in a before block, I'd like to be able to take some predetermined action based on the route. So, something like this:

```
before do
  check_authorization_for(:route_name)
end
```

Where ":route_name" would be something like "update" or "delete" or "create" or whatever. As it is now, I just have the code to check whether or not the current user has permission to perform the requested action at the beginning of each controller method. Our authorization scheme relies on information in our DB, and these permissions are keyed on the controller action, so if there's a way to determine the name of the route in the controller (i.e. if I can determine that the "update" action is being called), I can just have a single block to test for authorization instead of having to do the check in each action.

I feel certain there must be a very simple way to do this, but I can't seem to find any documentation on it. Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
before :show, :edit, :destroy do
    Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

Or if you prefer access directly to the route object:

```
request.route_obj
```

I.e.

```
request.route_obj.controller
```

If you want to mix current path, there is something similar to `current_page` in rails.

```
# http://localhost:3000/category/1/products/page/3
current_path('page' => 4) # => http://localhost:3000/category/1/products/page/4
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not really what I'm looking for. In our DB, we'll have an authorization record similar to {resource: 'foo', action: 'update', acl_id: 1234}, so in the controller, I'd like to be able to do something like "Actions.where(resource: 'foo', action: 'update')" in order to find the "acl_id" value. In this example, "update" is the controller action being called, so it wouldn't be in an "id" param, it would be the actual controller action. Does that make sense?

Comment: That was almost exactly what I needed. I ended up using request.route_obj.named.to_s, which got me what I was looking for. I had never seen or heard of request.route_obj, so that was incredibly helpful. Thanks so much.